# Help with an integral! $\int \frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{-2a}{r}+b}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi I want help with an integral, I've tried to solve it but I cant get anywhere. The integral is:

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{-2a}{r}+b}}$ Where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your efforts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $r=\frac{2a}{b}\sec^2 t$ your integral becomes $\frac{4a}{b^{3/2}}\int\sec^3 t dt$. The rest [is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed).